# Redefine variables which names depends of what user enters

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have some variables ordered by numebers, like ex1,ex2,ex3,etc (integers); i'd like to count how many times the user enter a letter of a number in a way such that if '1' is entered the program adds +1 to ex1, if 2 is enteres the program adds +1 to ex2- and so on (I can't use arrays because it's forbidden in the excersise). For example, if i ask the user to enter 15 numbers between 1 and 15, and i would like to count how many times each one of those is entered, the code i'm thinking of would be something like

```
for i:=1 to 15 do
    read(number);
    if number = i then
    Begin
        exi := exi + 1;
    End
```

Obviously that didn't work. Is it possible to redefine a variable doing something similar?.

Comment: Is the reason arrays are forbidden that they want you to use a linked list or some similar data structure?  That to me seems like your best bet.

Comment: I have a few questions... Just to be sure, are you really using Free Pascal ? What is the input (is that a string entered by the user when the program starts) ? Which structures or collections did you learned about (I mean, if the lector forbids the array, which is a very suitable data type for this task, which other structures do you know ? Have you heard e.g. about linked lists like I tried to mention in my overlooked comment or as @Mark mentioned in the above comment) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!. (1) - Yes, i'm using free pascal. (2) - The input is only a number here, (3)  The lector wants us this excersise using only structures if&else, for, while and repeat and data types integers, boolean and char; we can also use writeln and readln .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use arrays at all, you have just a couple of choices.

A case statement

```
for i := 1 to 15 do
begin
  Read(number);
  case number of
    1: ex1 := ex1 + number;
    2: ex2 := ex2 + number;
    // rest of possible values and variables
  else
    // Handle number that doesn't have a variable
  end;
end;
```

if..else statements

```
for i := 1 to 15 do
begin
  Read(number);
  if number = 1 then
    ex1 := ex1 + number
  else if number = 2 then
    ex2 := ex2 + number
  else if   // rest of possible values and variables

  else     // Handle number that doesn't have a variable

  end;
end;
```